# Python coverage and external executables

Tags: python, coverage

I have a project that has almost complete unit test coverage. There's only one statement that isn't covered and I can't work out a good way to do so. Say the project is called foo, I have foo/commands.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
[...]
def main(argv):
    [...]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    return main(sys.argv) # This line allegedly not covered by tests
```

I do have a test for it! foo/tests/test_commands.py:

```
import unittest
class CommandsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_direct_call(self):
        proc = subprocess.Popen(['python', 'foo/commands.py', 'help'], stdout=PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
        self.assertTrue(stdout.startswith('usage:'))
        self.assertEquals(0, proc.returncode)
```

(That's not my actual test, but it's along those lines.)

I use nose as my test runner:

```
nosetests --cover-erase --cover-tests --with-coverage --cover-package=foo -vs foo
```

The problem is that this particular statement isn't considered "covered", because I use plain python instead of coverage.py (or python-coverage as its called on Ubuntu). I could change it to python-coverage, but I don't really want to do that:

- It may not be available.
- If it is available, it may be named differently.
- It's ok if someone wants to run the test suite without the coverage stuff.

Right now, I have a dreadful hack to do it:

```
interpreter = 'coverage' in sys.modules ['python-coverage', 'run'] or ['python']
```

Not exactly the most readable code, but imagine the irony of using the more readable approach:

```
if 'coverage' in sys.modules:
    interpreter = ['python-coverage', 'run']
else:
    interpreter = ['python']
```

...only to realise that the "else:" branch ends up not getting called when coverage is enabled, so I just have another line of code that's not exercised by unit tests.

My goal is to fail the test suite if there isn't 100% coverage. I "need" the statement in foo/commands.py because it's a very convenient way to test things during development (in actual installs, it'll use distutils console_scripts magic to call into this file).

Ideas? Prior art? Anything?

**Note**: 100% coverage is by no means a guarantee that everything is great. Less than 100% is a guarantee, though, that there's something you're not testing. I can easily verify the 100% coverage, so I see no reason not to.

Comment: Why is your goal to fail the test suite if there isn't 100% coverage? What benefits will 100% coverage give you over 95% coverage, but more thorough testing around more critical areas?

Comment: 100% coverage is by no means a guarantee that everything is great. Less than 100% is a guarantee, though, that there's *something* you're not testing. I can easily verify the 100% coverage, so I see no reason not to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest option is to just mark the line as ignored by your coverage tests.  You know more than coverage.py does, you can just excuse the line from the measurements:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':     # pragma: no cover
    return main(sys.argv)
```

You can also use some tricks with coverage.py to get it to [measure code in launched subprocesses](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/subprocess.html). This sounds like the thing you are really looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the uncovered line from your .py file and use

```
python -c "import foo; foo.main(args);"
```

You can wrap that in an alias or a bash function.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution 1

Add the following code to your test runner:

```
import coverage
coverage.process_startup()
```

For a complete picture, see this sample `runtests.py` file (which is the entry point for running the tests).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import pytest
import coverage


def main():
    coverage.process_startup()
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('src'))
    return pytest.main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

## Solution 2

In the root of your project add a single file named `.pth` with the following content:

```
import coverage; coverage.process_startup()
```

## Solution 3

In the root of your project add a single file named `sitecustomize.py` with the following content:

```
import coverage
coverage.process_startup()
```